# Creating a blank/dummy SilverStripe 3.0 Page

Tags: silverstripe

How can I add blank or dummy pages to SS 3.0? I have been trying to create a dropdown list that would also include, supposed to be, blank pages or pages with no links as a placeholder to level out the navigation. Kindly check out the image provided for clarity.

[image]

Will this be possible in silverstripe?

Comment: tempted to '-1' this as it sounds like nonsense first hand, and the 'image provided for clarity'... d'oh??

Comment: but having a closer look it seems like you want to simply add some links to your navigation manually, probably rendered by `$Menu(x)` in your templates?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough, and that the image wasn't that good enough. I'll try to dig further with the answer provided. Thank you SO people, and sorry for the confusing question.
Cheers!

Comment: No need to apologise, this is a valid question. The image is vague, but you're actually pointing out a missing element in the SS CMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're wanted to insert a placeholder inside of a loop within your template. For example, when you're making a menu, you loop through $Level(1).

So if you were wanting to place a blank element in a certain spot during that loop, I would recommend using a conditional. SilverStripe conditionals aren't incredibly powerful, but they are very easy to understand.

Review [SilverStripe's template documentation](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/templates#conditional-logic). You can find loops [here](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/templates#looping-over-lists) too.

As an example, you could do this:

```
<li><a href="$Link">$MenuTitle</a></li>
<% if $Pos == 5 %>

    <li class="separator"></li>

<% end_if %>
```

<% end_loop %>

This will place an `<li>` of class `separator` after the fifth item.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I would check this out and post what I could find.